# url shows twice when submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

using codeigniter for the first time now, and trying out the upload file class they describe [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html). Now what happens is strange because once I submit the form with image selected, it displays error 404 which is understandable given for some reason the url shown in address bar turns out to be:

> http://mydomain.com/index.php/www.mydomain.com/index.php/do_upload

so it is repeating! that is causing the problem of 404 but i have no idea why it is happening?

the code am using for controller is:

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        //form_upload('userfile'); 
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = '/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Appreciate the support :)

EDIT: submit form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u might want to meddle with your .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem was to add http:// before the domain address in the base URL in the config file. That solved the problem. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

The bug is probably in your upload form. If the action is not a relative URL or starts with `http://`, e.g. you have specified "www.mydomain.com/index.php/do_upload" as the action, you will get that behaviour.

To fix, either prepend with "http://" or create a relative URL.

Comment: nope that's not the case. I included the form in my question.

Comment: Where? It's not there. I need your view file.

Comment: just did :) please check it out

Comment: Using Firebug (or view source or whatever), what is the action attribute on your form's opening tag?

Comment: nothing meaningful shows mate except css mainly and error 404...I just viewed source. I don't use firebug

Comment: It must show something. What is the specified action attribute of the `<form>` tag when you view the source of the upload form?

Comment: mate I just edited the base URL and now it is not showing double. It was missing http:// only at the beginning. now am getting upload path error but at least something I can work out. Thanks anyway for trying and seems like we were both looking in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('/upload/do_upload');?>
```

Not the '/' before 'upload'